# How does CoDi compares to the deep network?

Tags: deep-learning, model-evaluation, efficiency

I like the idea of [CoDi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDi) model which uses a von Neumann neighborhood method which has four types of cells.

How this models compares to the deep network in terms of efficiency?

Are there any scenarios where CoDi can outperform the deep network with hidden layers?